# Add names into a Multi-linked list

Tags: c, struct, doubly-linked-list

I am creating a multi-linked list of first name, last name, and phone number. I have an add function that allocates memory for the list but I don't know how to add into this list that will link first and last name in alphabetical order. How do I add to a multi-linked list? Is it much different from adding into a single linked list?

structures:

```
typedef struct node {
    char *first;
    char *last;
    long number;
    struct node *nextFirst;
    struct node *nextLast;
} Node;

typedef struct mlist {
    Node *headFirstName;
    Node *headLastName;
} MultiLinkedList;
```

add function:

```
MultiLinkedList *add(MultiLinkedList *list, char *first, char *last, long num) {
    // allocate a new node
    Node *newNode = malloc ( sizeof(Node) );
    newNode->first = malloc ( strlen(first) + 1 );
    strcpy(newNode->first, first);
    newNode->last = malloc ( strlen(last) + 1 );
    strcpy(newNode->last, last);
    newNode->number = num;
    // add this new node at the head of the "byFirst" list
    newNode->nextFirst = list->headFirstName;
    list->headFirstName = newNode;
    // add this new node at the head of the "byLast" list
    newNode->nextLast = list->headLastName;
    list->headLastName = newNode;
    // return the multi-list object with updated head pointers
    return list;
}
```

Edit: Here I have added in an updated code of my add function that I modified with adding to a list that I have used for a single linked list

```
MultiLinkedList *add(MultiLinkedList *list, char *first, char *last, long num) {

  Node *tempf = list->headFirstName;
  Node *templ = list->headLastName;

  while (tempf && templ) {
    if (strcasecmp(tempf->first, first) == 0 && strcasecmp(templ->last, last) == 0) {
      printf("Error - name %s %s already exists\n", first, last);
      return list;
    }
    tempf = tempf->nextFirst;
    templ = templ->nextLast;
  }

    // allocate a new node
    Node *newNode = malloc ( sizeof(Node) );
    newNode->first = malloc ( strlen(first) + 1 );
    strcpy(newNode->first, first);
    newNode->last = malloc ( strlen(last) + 1 );
    strcpy(newNode->last, last);
    newNode->number = num;
  newNode->nextFirst = NULL;
  newNode->nextLast = NULL;

  if(list == NULL)
    return newNode;
  if(strcasecmp(first, list->headFirstName->first) < 0){
    newNode->nextFirst = list->headFirstName;
    return newNode;
  }
  Node *prevf = list->headFirstName;
  Node *currf = list->headFirstName->nextFirst;
  while(currf && strcasecmp(currf->first, first) < 0){
    prevf = currf;
    currf = currf->nextFirst;
  }
  prevf->nextFirst = newNode;
  newNode->nextFirst = currf;

  if (list == NULL)
    return newNode;
  if (strcasecmp(last, list->headLastName->last) < 0) {
    newNode->nextLast = list->headLastName;
    return newNode;
  }
  Node *prevl = list->headLastName;
  Node *currl = list->headLastName->nextLast;
  while (currl && strcasecmp(currl->last, last) < 0) {
    prevl = currl;
    currl = currl->nextLast;
  }
  prevl->nextLast = newNode;
  newNode->nextLast = currl;

    // add this new node at the head of the "byFirst" list
    newNode->nextFirst = list->headFirstName;
    list->headFirstName = newNode;
  //list->headFirstName = addToFirstNameList(list->headFirstName, newNode);

    // add this new node at the head of the "byLast" list
    newNode->nextLast = list->headLastName;
    list->headLastName = newNode;
  //list->headLastName = addToLastNameList(list->headLastName, newNode);

    // return the multi-list object with updated head pointers
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're trying to accomplish? You want two sorted linked lists of these nodes?

Comment: @DanielPaczuskiBak Correct, I want a list of first names and list of last names that are linked together alphabetically so that I can search by a first name or last name and it will pull up that persons information(name and number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to write out the entire code for this, but here's the algorithm you want to use:

For the last names list, every time you insert, iterate through the list until you reach a last name that comes after the name you're trying to insert. Insert your current last name before this one. If you don't find one, insert it at the end.

Do the same for the first names list.

Comment: I updated my code in the question with what I believe is what you said to do

Comment: What's wrong with the code you wrote? Are you getting an error, do you have any sample input/output?

Comment: I am getting a warning: return for incompatible pointer type for return newNode. Input would be add Judy Garland 2058375609 then the output varies because there other function I have in my code that are supposed to print by first name that prints the list in alphabetical order based on first name

Comment: `newnode` is of type Node (which you are returning) but *add is supposed to return `MultiLinkedList`

So either you need to change the return type or you need to turn newnode into a multilinkedlist.

The "incompatible pointer type" error occurs when you're returning a type that the function isn't supposed to be returning.

Your original question has been answered so it'd be cool if you marked my answer as correct.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct. I also changed the return type to list and I do not have any errors now. Thank you